# ODBC call failed Violation of primary key

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc, relationship

(Beginner of SQL so I do apologize for any novice mistake that I made)

So essentially, I'm currently making an access form that allows the user to update their stock inside the warehouse. I'm using the ODBC link database in which I can store various data inside the server (the configuration for the database will be seen down below)
However, when I created a combo box that linked to a column(IDDH), it automatically pops up an error stating that it is violating the PK constraint whenever I switch to another column.At this point  I don't know what I did wrong since I already connected two tables with a relationship of one-to-many inside the SQL along with connecting it on Microsoft Access(Just in case). And connect Foreign Key in the dbo.DonHang table (ProductID)

Here is my configuration
SQL:
[image]

Relationship in Access
[image]

The error in the access form whenever I switched to a different column in the combo box
[image]

If you want to require more information. Please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: It seems you have a duplicate value to be saved in new record for a primary key. 1- Primary keys doesn't accept duplicate values. 2- It is not normal to connect primary key to a combo box as this will imply selecting duplicate values from the drop list. Please clarify what you need from this combo box linked to primary key.

Comment: It also looks like you linked on the wrong columns. While SSMS doesn't display this, I think it's safe to assume the link is ProductID <-> ProductID, not ProductID <-> DateOfSupply because that doesn't really make sense

Comment: @mamadsp I'm trying to illustrate the order ID in which help to auto fill the remaining boxes below . For example, if i select this particular ID then the rest of the ID in which inlucde name,adress, quantity and etc will be automatically recognized and fill in the box                 This is the video that im trying to do : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXGtB7WiBgQ

Comment: @ErikA Despite being linked just what you have said, the error still remains there

Comment: You don't need to link the Combo to the primary key but you need to set the **Row Source** of combo box to this primary key (this will fill the combo box list with values in it without changing values) then in the query on the form level you set the primary key to equal the value of the combobox. Then set the OnChange event of combo box to requery the form.

Answer (score 0):

You base one form directly on the main table. Not a sql join.
You then create a sub form with the "many" entries for the one record. And again that form is NOT based on some sql join, but ONLY the linked child table.

You don't try and use sql joins to solve this kind of data editing in Access (using sql server does not change this). So you need a main form (based ONLY directly on the ONE linked table of master (parent) records. You then have a sub form and again it is based directly on the child linked table (again not some sql query).

So, for editing main records and child records? you use a form + sub form in Access to achieve this goal. And this setup will also work well with sql server linked tables.

But all in all? You don't try and edit sql joined data. you build up the main form, and drop in a sub form to a classic and common editing of master/child data in Access.

If you really want to edit both as one row? Well, you can often edit but you not be allowed in general to add rows. But if the sql VIEW you create allows editing of rows (you can test/try this in SSMS), then if you save that query in SSMS as a view? Then simply link the view to Access and you can edit the one row, but there are limitations in terms of adding new rows etc. it really depends on your goal.

but, at the end of the day, editing of master + child records is NOT achieved by a sql join query, but that of editing each table separate, or a form + sub form in access.